# loadPlayer function inside success function is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I get the following message when trying the following code.

```
angular.js:9419 Referenceerror: loadplayer is not defined.
```

Here is my code:

```
(function getAllAlbums(){
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "api/playlist.php?type=playlist",
})
.success(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  loadPlayer(response);
})
.error(function(response){
 console.log(response);
})

})();
```

Down the file I have the function:

```
jQuery(function loadPlayer($) {
var supportsAudio = !!document.createElement('audio').canPlayType;
if (supportsAudio) {.......
```

Why do I get the message that `loadPlayer` is undefined??

Comment: You are not in the same scope.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I'm slightly concerned about the arguments to `loadPlayer`. The function definition contains a single argument called `$`, which is (conventionally) the global jQuery object. The `jQuery(loadPlayer)` part should call `loadPlayer` with no arguments. But then you've got `loadPlayer(response)`, which uses a completely different argument. Why would you need the jQuery object as an argument? Do you need the `response` argument? Should this be two different functions?

Answer (score 1):

Because of different scope.
Your first function was declared in a self invoked function.
Your second function was declared i don't even know where. 
What you ca do is to declare both of them in a one scope. Smth like this.

```
(function ($) {

$(document).onload = function () {
    function loadPlayer($) {}
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "api/playlist.php?type=playlist",
        })
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            loadPlayer(response);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
}
}(jQuery));
```